# Need to encrypt the passwords to a web application without making the secret key available to the attacker

Tags: security, encryption, web-applications

I want to encrypt the passwords used in my web application. In normally we will encrypt the passwords and save it to the property file and later we will decode it. But here if the source code is an open source then the attacker can find the decoding method in the source code and can get the password.

Another way is save the password into a key store file and then access it with the key store password. But again same problem is there, attacker can see the key store password.

Could anyone tell me any solution to this?

Comment: Why won't you use a public/private key to do the needful? Your private key will never be made public so even if your encryption algorithm is known your private key is never exposed

Comment: how will u give your private key to decryption algorithm? . Anyhow that private key will be available inside the source code right?. So that attacker can use that to decrypt.

Comment: Not at all! There are several ways to do it, being a big AWS fan you can simply read the key from a secure S3 bucket which you can and only you can access. You can have the key as an input to your program...so many ways

Comment: What's the purpose of those passwords? If you want to authenticate *your users*, you should not encrypt at all. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: @Ruskin thanks for your reply. I will consider this

Comment: @ Arjtom Password is used to open a key store file

Answer (score 0):

You could make the secret key an environment variable and then refer to it like that in code (python: `os.environ('secretKey')`), or (I'm assuming you're storing your code on github) you can store the secret key in a file and add that file to .gitignore